# Occasional PermissionError when dict-writing to csv

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, permissionerror

I've written a tkinter app in Python 3.7, which extracts from main CSV, pre-filtered by user, information into smaller reports. My issue is that while writing filtered data from main CSV into report I occasionally get a PermissionError:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mdiakuly\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/report_extractor_hil_sil/report_extractor.py", line 286, in report_generation_prep
    self.report_generation(names_list, relevant_params, specific_value, extracted_file)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/report_extractor_hil_sil/report_extractor.py", line 344, in report_generation
    processing_data(rd,column)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/report_extractor_hil_sil/report_extractor.py", line 336, in processing_data
    writing_new_report(gathering_row)
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/report_extractor_hil_sil/report_extractor.py", line 299, in writing_new_report
    with open(extracted_file, 'a+', newline='') as write_in:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/reporter/Partial_report_14_10_2021T15-13-12.csv'
```

Once it has extracted only one row and through an error, another time it did whole extraction with no error, and few other times it extracted thousands of rows and through an error.
CSV file which is being written into was never opened during info extraction.

Has anyone faced the same issue or maybe has an idea how to fix it?

```
    def writing_new_report(complete_row):

        with open(extracted_file, 'a+', newline='') as write_in:
            wt = csv.DictWriter(write_in, delimiter=';', fieldnames=relevant_params)
            if self.debug:
                print(complete_row)
            wt.writerow(complete_row)

    def processing_data(r_d,column='def'):

        for idx, row in enumerate(r_d): #looping through major csv
            self.progress.update()
            if self.debug:
                print(f'{idx:}',end=' / ')
            gathering_row = {}
            if column != 'def':
                if row[column] not in names_list:
                    continue
                else:
                    names_list.remove(row[column])
                    pass
            else:
                pass

            for param, value in zip(relevant_params,specific_value):
                self.progress.update()
                if self.debug:
                    print(f'{row[param]:}',end=' / ')
                gathering_row[param] = row[param]
                if value == '---- All ----':
                    pass
                elif value != row[param]:
                    if self.debug:
                        print(f'{row[param]:} - Skipped')
                    break

                if param == relevant_params[len(relevant_params)-1]:
                    if self.debug:
                        print(f'{row[param]:} - Written')
                    writing_new_report(gathering_row)
```

Comment: you can [edit] your question and add that info there, also then remove that comment and also provide a [mre]

Comment: This is not a [mre]. Could you reproduce it with a smaller example? The problem occurs when opening `extracted_file`, but we can't see how this variable is defined and if it's used somewhere else. In most cases this error really means what it says: the app doesn't have permission to open the file, so either your code did open the file and not close it yet, or some other proccess has opened the file.

Comment: Also, double (or triple) check if you don't have the file open in a text editor or Excel. If you had opened it in another application, make sure to really close that application, since some applications do not properly release the file resources, which could also cause this error.

Comment: Final thought: does this problem also occur if you don't use `tkinter`? So is it possible to extract the "business logic" (the CSV reading and writing part) into a seperate function, which you directly call from a command-line app?

Comment: once you make it down to a MRE the answer may become more clear.  However, I'd make sure the place your are running the code isn't in OneDrive, or some other backup/sync folder.  Since it doesn't always happen it could be very likely that the file is simply getting locked by another process/windows.